# Configure printer for Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2Y_GC4Zm54 we are trying to print out the shipments as indicated in the video. This would be a great approximation as it would take us closer to printing documents from a new page we created called "Work Orders" which is the fnal requirement.

I have 2 questions:

1. In the video there is a customization package called "Devicehubinstalled" that adds the Print Queues and Scale pages. Is this customization available for the community? if so, where could I find it?
2. In this Help article from Acumatica (https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=de3b7e31-58f7-4e36-a6ec-d40ac9755037) is described how to configure a USB printer in ther server or workstation. I am currently trying it locally and the request is being sent to the printer and it's being placed in queue but without any results. Has anyone face a similar scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: It is available as part of the product starting in 2018R1. Before that I am unsure where you can access the customization. Here is a reference to setup in 2018R1: https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(1))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=43536fa2-77b9-4aaa-8248-0cf5d533e723

Comment: There is Customization for 2017 R2 in the Advanced Fulfillment package, but it is stilll in Pre-Release

Answer (score 2):

1) There is a section to enable scale integration on the partner portal: https://portal.acumatica.com/downloads/advanced-fulfillment-download/ 
You have to scroll down to the Configuration area. On this page, you can find customizations for different versions of Acumatica. Starting from 2018R1 the DeviceHub for Printers is included in the core product as a feature and there is a separate customization to activate scales and packaging there.

2) The issue can be that the labels printer is not shared. Please check this and change the shared name on the batch file, if needed. You can also have a look at the article about labels printing configuration here: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/technical-tuesday-printing-shipping-labels-using-acumatica/